# Text search query for text "other" always returns no results?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

My data looks like this:

```
[{"id" : 1, "question" : "Other specified dermatomycoses", ... },
 {"id" : 6, "question" : "Other specified disorders of joint, site unspecified", ... }]
```

plus a few other records.

If I run

```
db.questions.find({$text:{$search:'other'}}).count()
```

I always get 0. But if I run

```
db.questions.find({$text:{$search:'specified'}}).count()
```

I get the 2 that I expect. Most searches work properly, but not the word "other". Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a commonplace occurance in "text search" operations on many engines, where "stop words" are **always** omitted from the words that are tokenized and therefore searchable.

Common words are "the", "and", "then" etc. But the full listings can be viewed in the [source tree](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/tree/master/src/mongo/db/fts). `stop_words_[language].txt`.

[English list here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/fts/stop_words_english.txt)

If your intent is to match words such as listed there, then use a [`$regex`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) search instead:

```js
db.questions.find({ "question": { "$regex": "other" } })
```

This is not really a MongoDB thing, but it happens with most text search engines, and is "by design".

Comment: Ahhh interesting. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Blakes said it all, as an added tip; you can use **$language** operator with value none to **ignore stop words** and **stemming**. 
Here is an example how to use it :

```
db.questions.find({ $text: { $search: "other", $language: "none" } })
```

Answer (score 1):

When creating a text index in MongoDB, if you do not specify a language value it will use **english** by default and its stop words. If you want to be able to search by the stop words you will have to set the default language value of your text index to "none".

Create your index like this:

```
db.questions.createIndex({ theSearchField : 'text' }, { default_language: 'none' })
```

Then you should be able to run your query

```
db.questions.find({$text:{$search:'other'}}).count()
```